# Cover cubiods with spheres

Tags: c#, geometry, cover

I am looking for an algorithm to the following problem : 
I have N cuboids of arbitrary size defined by : xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin,zmax and I need to cover them with a minimum number of spheres with fixed size D. If the cuboid doesn't fit into the sphere I can divide it in other smaller cuboids.

Comment: Please post example code of what you've achieved so far, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I've tried sorting all the cuboids from bigger to smaller and divided all the bigger ones to cuboids that could fit the sphere. After that I've covered each cuboid but I've ended up covering the same cuboid more than once and it's not exactly an optimal solution to the problem.

Comment: Please post the code, and we (maybe) can try to fix it.